# Accessing arcpy.mapping .tif layer object?

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, valueerror

Can someone tell me why I am getting this value error when attempting to access the Montreal.tif layer object?

The first three lines access the object and set the transparency perfectly well, but when I attempt to access it using the following 4 lines I get the illustrated ValueError?

I need the second method since the b variable (Montreal) will change.

ArcGIS Desktop v10.1, ArcInfo license.

[image]

The following is a successful workaround (among others), but I'm still not sure why the above was giving me an error?

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

b = "Montreal"
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if "{0}.tif".format(b) in lyr.name:
        lyr.transparency = 50
```

Comment: What is actual name of layer in table of content?

Answer (score 2):

The code in your picture, where the error is seen, has an extra level of quotes i.e.

```
c = '"{0}.tif"'.format(b)
```

so try:

```
c = '{0}.tif'.format(b)
```

or:

```
c = "{0}.tif".format(b)
```

instead.

Comment: That was actually the first syntax I originally tried and it wasn't working.  Trying it again from another machine this afternoon and it works... odd. Anyway small issue. Thanks PolyGeo, great work as always.
Should I delete this post? I'm not sure it contributes anything to the site..

Comment: Rather than trying to delete it, which you won't be able to do because it has an upvoted answer, I think it would gain more value if you supplement the picture in the question with your code and error as text so that it is available to future searches.